# display horizontal scrollbar of Yajra datatable at the bottom of browser window

Tags: css, laravel, yajra-datatable

Yajra datatable displays Horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the webpage. but i want to display it at the bottom of browser window. the datatable is present inside a card.

i tried this in style tag but didnt work.

```
`
    <style>
    .dataTables_scrollBody {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    </style>

`
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your styles is being overridden by other classes/styles.
I think to be safe, you might consider adding it to a parent  for example, and assign `!important` to your styles.

```
<style>
  .parent-div {
      position: relative;
  }

  .dataTables_scrollBody {
      overflow-x: scroll !important;
      overflow-y: hidden !important;
      position: absolute !important;
      bottom: 0 !important;
  }
</style>
<div class="parent-div">
  <!-- Your DataTable -->
  
</div>
```